# Graph automorphisms and union of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group, algebraic-graph-theory, directed-graphs, directed-union

I have a question, so please allow me to ask here.
Thank you.

My question is:

Let $G$ be a union of directed graphs $G_1, \ldots , G_n$, that is, $G=G_1\cup\cdots\cup G_n$.

If $f:G\to G$ is a morphism of directed graphs such that $f|_{G_i}$ is an automorphism of $G_i$ for any $i=1,2,\dots, n$, then is $f$ an automorphism of $G$?

Comment: What do you mean by union? Do you e.g. need that the vertex sets are disjoint?

Comment: Sorry,

For two directed graphs $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$, where $V_i$ is the set of vertices of $G_i$ and $E_i$ is the set of arrows of $G_i$, 

the union $G_1\cup G_2$ is $(V_1\cup V_2, E_1\cup E_2)$.
Here, I do not need that this union is disjoint.